# Conditional Densities

Tags: probability, statistics

So two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$

I want to find the conditional densities of $X$ and $Y$ given that $X>Y$.

How can I find these conditional densities and their expected values? i.e $\mathbb E(X|X>Y)$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ defined on the same probability space? If so then what is their joint distribution? Are they independent maybe?

Comment: Yes they are independent

Comment: You should add to your question in an edit, because it is essential information. Without it your question cannot be answered.

Comment: I have edited the question. Are you able to provide an answer now by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (since there is no way to proceed with assuming some joint distribution, and this is the most natural one) then the question has already been answered here [Conditional density question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320658/conditional-density-question/3320694#3320694).

In particular, $\mathbb E(X\mid X>Y)=\int _0^1 2x^2\ dx=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: I tried to understand that comment of yours but I could not make sense out of the first part (the triangle part)

Comment: Consider the pair $(X,Y)$. It is a random point in the plane. Before the conditioning, it belongs to the unit square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. You can think of the conditioning as cutting the square in half along the line $x=y$. The bottom right half is all that remains after conditioning. Since the area is half, the density must double so as to maintain a total integral of $1$. That is the entire concept...

Comment: Oh right. That makes sense. Thank you that was very helful

Comment: If the questions are answered, you can mark them as such using the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Under condition $X>Y$ we are dealing with uniform distribution on the triangle: $$\Delta:=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\mid x>y\}$$

The PDF of this joint distribution is constant on that triangle and takes value $0$ outside the triangle.

As always its integral must take value $1$ and this together leads to PDF:$$f_{X,Y\mid X>Y}(x,y)=2\mathbf1_{\Delta}(x,y)$$where $\mathbf1_{\Delta}$ denotes the indicator function of set $\Delta$.

Then we find: $$\mathbb E[X\mid X>Y]=\int xf_{X,Y\mid X>Y}(x,y)dydx=2\int_0^1\int_0^xxdydx=2\int_0^1x\int_0^xdydx=$$$$2\int_0^1x^2dx=\frac23$$

You can find the marginal distributions of the conditional distribution on the usual way by finding for $x\in[0,1]$:$$f_{X\mid X>Y}(x)=\int f_{X,Y\mid X>Y}(x,y)dy=2\int_0^xdy=2x\tag1$$and for $y\in[0,1]$ similarly:$$f_{Y\mid X>Y}(y)=\int f_{X,Y\mid X>Y}(x,y)dx=2\int_y^1dy=2(1-y)$$

Outside interval $[0,1]$ these marginals evidently both take value $0$.

Also note that $(1)$ reveals another way to find $\mathbb E[X\mid X>Y]$:$$\mathbb E[X\mid X>Y]=\int_0^1xf_{X\mid X>Y}(x)dx=\int_0^1x\cdot2xdx=\frac23$$